# Converting a TypeScript build event into an External Tools command

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript, build-events, external-tools

I'm working on TypeScript files with Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.  Since the Web Essentials addon doesn't work with Express editions, and rebuilding the entire project every time I update a script is starting to take too long, I was hoping to convert the following build event (from the TypeScript project template) into an 'External Tools' command that I can place on my toolbar.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files" />
  <Message Text="Executing tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
  <Exec Command="tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

Unfortunately... this has kinda lost me.  I can't find any documentation on `$(TypeScriptSourceMap)`, nor the `@()` and `%()` macros.  It doesn't seem to appreciate me copying the command directly either. (Even after converting the HTML entities.)

What could I enter into the External Tools dialog in order to mimic this build event?

I'll try to write a PS script or some such as a workaround, but this would lack the functionality of only working on files with the 'TypeScriptCompile' build action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(TypeScriptSourceMap)` comes from about 4 lines earlier in the project file. It's simply `" --sourcemap"` when in the debug configuration and `""` otherwise.

The `@()` syntax here basically means "For every project item whose build action is `TypeScriptCompile`, put its full path in double-quotes and join those resulting items by a space.

An emerging best practice for TypeScript projects is to have a "project.ts" file that looks like this:

**project.ts**

```
/// <reference path="file1.ts" />
/// <reference path="file2.ts" />
/// ... and so on
```

**file1.ts**

```
/// <reference path="project.ts" />

class alpha { ... }
```

**file2.ts**

```
/// <reference path="project.ts" />

class beta { ... }
```

With that setup, you can simply run `tsc project.ts` or `tsc project.ts --out app.ts` and the right thing will happen.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know off hand where that `@()` syntax is documented?  TSC is complaining about not finding the file named "(TypeScriptCompile", so it looks like that doesn't get parsed when executing external tools.  I may switch to using that project.ts trick anyway, but this stuff is certainly good to know.

Comment: Getting a very odd error with this trick you suggested: `Unknown extension for file: "scripts\project.ts". Only .ts and .d.ts extensions are allowed.`  Same goes for when I provide the full path.

Comment: The insane "wrong extension" error has been fixed in 0.8.1.1; I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: Hah, yeah.  Just realized it ment to say the file was missing.  I was missing a directory in the path.  Thanks again.